# Variadic heterogenous FREE macro

Tags: c, macros

I want a macro to free multiple (variadic number) pointers of **different type**. Based on similar questions in SO I made this code which seems to work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* your compiler may need to define i outside the loop */
#define FREE(ptr1, ...) do{\
    void *elems[] = {ptr1, __VA_ARGS__};\
    unsigned num = sizeof(elems) / sizeof(elems[0]);\
    for (unsigned i=0; i < num; ++i) free(elems[i]);\
} while(0)


int main(void) 
{
    double *x = malloc(sizeof(double)); /* your compiler may need a cast */
    int    *y = malloc(   sizeof(int)); /* ditto */

    FREE(x, y); 
}
```

My question is

- Is the creation of a `void*` array correct in this context? (I saw the same trick with `*int[]`, so the question is will a `*void[]` do what I expect)
- Is the code C99 compliant, are there any compilers that would have problems with this?

Comment: If you're aiming for C99, why do you declare `i` outside the loop?! And why do you cast the result of `malloc`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm somewhat uptight when writing C; The ghost of past versions made me do it :P ... will edit the question, thnx

Comment: Side notes: 1. You can get rid of that `ptr1` in your macro. 2. Declare `i` as `unsigned` (similarly to `num`). 3. Function `main` should return a value. 4. You should also include `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @barakmanos 1. Don't won't to risk creating 0sized arrays and have incomprehensible error messages due to macro expansion (better off with a mandatory argument) 2. Agree 3. Implicit return types

Comment: It will not create a 0-size array. You'll get a compilation error if you try to "invoke" `FREE()`.

Comment: your comment "prior to C99 you need..."  but It does not work in C99 previous

Comment: @barakmanos Last return value of main in C99 can be omitted.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ok, a little bit of confusion there. I added a more generic message; I'm using VS2012 and its implementation of C99 doesn't include those feature, I left the comments for those that are stuck in the middle (as I am)

Comment: If you don't get rid of `ptr1`, I think you *can't* legally use this with only one argument (although most compilers will allow it and the `...` can be empty). While it doesn't add anything to `free` in that case, it's nice for such things to be generic.

Comment: @Leushenko Yes, you can

Comment: @barakmanos The error messages would be `Not enough actual parameters for macro FREE` vs `syntax error }`. Both are correct but  I opted for the first

Comment: VS2012 doesn't have C99 support, does it? As I recall first signs of improved support started in VS2013. Do you compile it with VS2012 in C++ mode?

Comment: While I have no doubt that this macro could work, all it seems to do is to remove some typing at the expense of readability and memory use (unless free list is big, which is usually not the case).

Comment: @barakmanos After the answer by Leushenko, I'll have to admit the trade offs are not quite cutting it for the `warnings` case. Thnx for initially pointing the `ptr1` problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential usability problem with this is that it doesn't scale to freeing only a single pointer, similar to the regular `free`. While this isn't necessary (since you could require the user to spot this and use `free`), it's usually elegant for things to be as generic as possible and automatically scale themselves to fit such use cases.

[C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (also [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) standard section 6.10.3 paragraph 4:

> If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an ellipsis ... Otherwise, there **shall be more arguments** in the invocation than there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the `...`).

i.e. in strictly conforming C, the `__VA_ARGS__` must be used. GCC will even highlight this for you (a compiler can't prove something *is* compliant, but it can warn you when it isn't) when using `-std=c99 -Wall -pedantic`:

> `test.c: In function 'main':`
>      `test.c:18:11: warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used [enabled by default]
>        FREE(x);
>              ^`

Technically you don't need the actual value, just the trailing comma (`FREE(x,);` - an empty macro argument is still an argument, and the array initializer it populates also allows trailing commas), but that's not very... integrated with the language.

In practice real compilers won't directly object to missing rest-args, but they might warn about it (as shown above), because a non-fatal error is often reasonable to interpret as a sign that something is wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, so we're back to `lose ptr1` ?

Comment: Well, it's an argument for it (that it might cause warnings, which some people don't like). If you still think the tradeoff against better potential error messages is worthwhile, keep it.

Comment: @Nope compliance beats warnings, will go credit barak manos as well. Thnx for being thorough (I'll leave the question uneditted so that this answer stays in context)

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty cool, and yes it's correct to use `void *`.

You could improve it somewhat (more `const`, and of course use `size_t` instead of `unsigned`) but in general it seems alright.

Also, drop the casts in `main()`, [there's no need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and doing so can mask actual errors so it's just bad.

To address [@Leushenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28042439/28169), you might be able to glue something together by adding an extra macro expansion step that always adds a NULL in the varargs macro call. That way, you're never going to call the actual varargs macro with just a single argument, even if the toplevel macro is called with only one. Of course, calling `free(NULL)` is always safe and well-defined, so that should work.

Comment: Actual errors which the OP *is actually committing* by not including `stdlib.h` :-)

Comment: It looks like VS implements C99 in its own "flavour" , I need to use the initial code, but I updated the question to comply with the corrections (and C99 ), thnx